# How does RSpec's expect work in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

While going through Ruby On Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl,in the section where the author writes integration test to validate his Signup page, he has used code spinet bellow. I got what the code does but couldn't get my head around the 'how' part i.e. couldn't understand order of execution.

```
expect { click_button "Create my account" }.not_to change(User, :count)
```

Can someone please explain the semantics of the above chain of methods and blocks and how they fit together?

Comment: This is not Capybara, it is RSpec.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You'd use `expect ... change` to verify that a particular method call changes -- or does not change -- some other value. In this case:

```
expect { click_button "Create my account" }.not_to change(User, :count)
```

will cause rspec to do the following:

1. Run `User.count` and note the value returned. (This can be specified as a receiver and a method name, like `(User, :count)` in  your example, or as an arbitrary block of code, like `{ User.count }`.
2. Run `click_button "Create my account"` which is a Capybara method that simulates a mouse click on a link.
3. Run `User.count` again.
4. Compare the results of #1 and #3. If they differ, the example fails. If they're the same, it passes.

Other ways to use `expect ... change`:

```
expect { thing.destroy }.to change(Thing, :count).from(1).to(0)
expect { thing.tax = 5 }.to change { thing.total_price }.by(5)
expect { thing.save! }.to raise_error
expect { thing.symbolize_name }.to change { thing.name }.from(String).to(Symbol)
```

Some docs are [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/expect-change).

How it does this is a bit arcane, and it's not at all necessary to understand how it works in order to use it. A call to `expect` is defining a structure for rspec to execute, using rspec's own custom DSL and system of "matchers." Gary Bernhardt has a rather neat [screencast](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/building-rspec-from-scratch) in which he argues that the mystery of rspec actually falls out naturally from a dynamic language like ruby. It's not a good introduction to *using* rspec, but if you're curious about how it all works, you might find it interesting.

**UPDATE**

After seeing your comment on another answer, I'll add a bit about the order of operations. The unintuitive trick is that it's the *matcher* (`change` in this case) that executes all of the blocks. `expect` has a lambda, `not_to` is an alias for `should_not` whose job is to pass the lambda on to the matcher. The matcher in this case is `change` which knows to execute its own argument once, then execute the lambda that it was passed (the one from `expect`), then run its own argument again to see if things changed. It's tricky because the line looks like it should execute left to right, but since most of the pieces are just passing around blocks of code, they can and do shuffle them into whatever order makes the most sense to the matcher.

I'm not an expert on the rspec internals, but that's my understanding of the basic idea.

Comment: Most detailed and helpful answer I have ever read on SO. I would upvote this 100x if I could. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's an excerpt from from [Ryan Bates Railscast on Request Specs and Capybara](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara)

```
require 'spec_helper'  

describe "Tasks" do  
  describe "GET /tasks" do  
    it "displays tasks" do  
      Task.create!(:name => "paint fence")  
      visit tasks_path  
      page.should have_content("paint fence")  
    end  
  end  

  describe "POST /tasks" do  
    it "creates a task" do  
      visit tasks_path  
      fill_in "Name", :with => "mow lawn"  
      click_button "Add"  
      page.should have_content("Successfully added task.")  
      page.should have_content("mow lawn")  
    end  
  end  
end
```

And here's an excerpt from [the docs on RSPec Expectations](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change)

```
describe Counter, "#increment" do
  it "should increment the count" do
    expect{Counter.increment}.to change{Counter.count}.from(0).to(1)
  end

  # deliberate failure
  it "should increment the count by 2" do
    expect{Counter.increment}.to change{Counter.count}.by(2)
  end
end
```

So basically, the

```
expect { click_button "Create my account" }.not_to change(User, :count)
```

is part RSpec:

```
expect {...}.not_to change(User, :count)
```

and part Capybara

```
click_button "Create my account"
```

(Here's [a link to the Capyabara DSL](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) -- you can search for `click_button`)

It sounds like you're looking for an overall example with them both. This isn't a perfect example, but it could look something like this:

```
describe "Tasks" do  
  describe "GET /tasks" do  
    it "displays tasks" do  
      expect { click_button "Create my account" }.not_to change(User, :count)
    end  
  end 
end
```

Comment: Tnx for the nice examples. I was more of interested to know  the semantics of of the expression such as how dose `change(..)` get executed twice and the overall order of execution.